# Python-polars: rolling_sum where the window_size from another column

Tags: python, python-polars

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": pl.date_range(
            low=datetime(2023, 2, 1),
            high=datetime(2023, 2, 5),
            interval="1d"),
        "periods": [2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
        "quantity": [10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
        "calculate": [22, 26, 30, 16, 18]
    }
)
```

The column calculate is what I want. This is done by a rolling_sum where the `window_size` parameter is taken from the `periods` column, rather than a fixed value.

I can do the following (window_size=2):

```
df.select(pl.col("quantity").rolling_sum(window_size=2))
```

However, I get an error when I try and do this:

```
df.select(pl.col("quantity").rolling_sum(window_size=pl.col("periods")))
```

This is the error -

```
TypeError: argument 'window_size': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
```

How do I pass the value of `window_size` based on another column? I also looked at using `groupie_rolling` but could not figure it out as well.

Comment: looks like `window_size` needs to be `int`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to pass a column of `int`.

Comment: A column of `int` type isn't the same thing as an Expr that resolves to an `int`.  That's the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to @jqurious's but (I think) a bit simplified

```
df.lazy() \
    .with_row_count('i') \
    .with_columns(
        window = 
            pl.arange(
                pl.col("i"), 
                pl.col("i") + pl.col("periods")),
            qty=pl.col('quantity').list()
) \
.with_columns(
    rollsum=pl.col('qty').arr.take(pl.col('window')).arr.sum()
) \
.select(pl.exclude(['window','qty','i'])) \
.collect()
```

It works on the same concept but it just essentially recreates the whole `quantity` column as a list then using the `window` column to filter that list to the corresponding values and sum them up.

Another method is to just use a loop which will be more memory efficient.

First, you want to get all the unique values of periods, then initialize a column in the df for the rolling_sum, reverse the order, and then replace the column with a calculation for every period.  At the end, put the rows back in the original order.

```
periods=df.get_column('periods').unique()
df=df.with_columns(pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Float64()).alias("rollsum")).sort('date',reverse=True)
for period in periods:
    df=df.with_columns((pl.when(pl.col('periods')==period).then(pl.col('quantity').rolling_sum(window_size=period)).otherwise(pl.col('rollsum'))).alias('rollsum'))
df=df.sort('date')
df
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong - anytime I use `.list()` it seems to kill performance. Do you see any slowdowns if you increase the size e.g. `df = pl.concat([df] * 7500)`?

Comment: Yeah, it basically copies the whole column into every row. It's one of those trade offs between readability and scalability.  It might only be copying pointers but it still scales poorly.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's copying the whole list as the MEM% goes quite high. I wonder if this could be improved as this is a much simpler solution.

Comment: @jqurious I put in an entirely different method that is unpolars like but will be must more memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this should be easier to do which suggests I may be missing something obvious.

As a workaround - you could use the row count to generate row indexes for the windows.

```
(  
   df
   .with_row_count()
   .with_columns(
      window = 
         pl.arange(
            pl.col("row_nr"), 
            pl.col("row_nr") + pl.col("periods")))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 6)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr | date                | periods | quantity | calculate | window    │
│ ---    | ---                 | ---     | ---      | ---       | ---       │
│ u32    | datetime[μs]        | i64     | i64      | i64       | list[i64] │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2       | 10       | 22        | [0, 1]    │
│ 1      | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | 2       | 12       | 26        | [1, 2]    │
│ 2      | 2023-02-03 00:00:00 | 2       | 14       | 30        | [2, 3]    │
│ 3      | 2023-02-04 00:00:00 | 1       | 16       | 16        | [3]       │
│ 4      | 2023-02-05 00:00:00 | 1       | 18       | 18        | [4]       │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

You could `.explode()` the window and use `.take()` + `.search_sorted()` to find the corresponding values.

`.groupby()` can be used to combine the window values again.

```
(  
   df
   .with_row_count()
   .with_columns(
      window = 
         pl.arange(
            pl.col("row_nr"), 
            pl.col("row_nr") + pl.col("periods")))
   .explode("window")
   .with_columns(
      rolling = 
         pl.col("quantity")
           .take(pl.col("row_nr").search_sorted("window")))
   .groupby("row_nr", maintain_order=True)
   .agg([
      pl.exclude("rolling").first(), 
      pl.col("rolling").sum()
   ])
)
```

```
shape: (5, 7)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ row_nr | date                | periods | quantity | calculate | window | rolling │
│ ---    | ---                 | ---     | ---      | ---       | ---    | ---     │
│ u32    | datetime[μs]        | i64     | i64      | i64       | i64    | i64     │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ 0      | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2       | 10       | 22        | 0      | 22      │
│ 1      | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | 2       | 12       | 26        | 1      | 26      │
│ 2      | 2023-02-03 00:00:00 | 2       | 14       | 30        | 2      | 30      │
│ 3      | 2023-02-04 00:00:00 | 1       | 16       | 16        | 3      | 16      │
│ 4      | 2023-02-05 00:00:00 | 1       | 18       | 18        | 4      | 18      │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────┴─────────┘
```